# wso2emm fails to start in the public address

Tags: wso2

We have a problem in the server configuration wich left our EMM server out of service , we need to reestablish the connectivity.

We had our instance of wso2emm already running correctly for iOS and Android.
But due to a change of server configuration from our enterprise the way of addressing the IP to the server has changed.

Now we don’t have the server assigned directly to a public IP , we need to use public addressing in the server.

We got this error at the start of the server: "Error in initializing thrift transport org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Could not bind to port 10397"
So we  know we need now to configure our EMM server for being able to connect to out public ip over NAT.

We have not found how to do it in the EMM documentation.
We tried changing the general server configurations, such carbon.xml or sso-idp-config.xml and other files (axis2.xml, api-manager.xml) replacing the local IP by the public.

We are stuck with the same error. Can you please give us some documentation to address this issue of configuration?

We are sure we have connectivity and the ports are open , we already tested that.

Comment: Did you find a solution, I'm looking for this issue as well.